# How to define AngularJs service with REST (using $resource) and other more method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I want to define more methods on the same settings service other than the REST method I already have.
I don't know how.

```
 var settingsService = angular.module('settingsService',['ngResource']);

 settingsService.service('SettingsService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:9000/settings', {}, {
        update: {method:'PUT'},
    });
}]);
```

How can I add more method and members to this service? 
For example:

```
 var settingsService = angular.module('settingsService',['ngResource']);

 settingsService.service('SettingsService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost:9000/settings', {}, {
        update: {method:'PUT'},
    });

  var x; //some member

  this.func1 = function(){
     // do something
  }
}]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
settingsService.service('SettingsService', ['$resource', function($resource){

   var _settingsServiceFactory = [];

   var _varX = 'someValue';
   var _functionX = function() { // do something };

    var _resourceSrvc = function() {
    return  $resource('http://localhost:9000/settings', {}, {
        update: {method:'PUT'}});

    settingsServiceFactory.VarX  = _varX;
    settingsServiceFactory.FunctionX  =_functionX ; 
settingsServiceFactory.ResourceSrvc  = _resourceSrvc;

return settingsServiceFactory;
});
```

OR simply write

```
settingsService.service('SettingsService', ['$resource', function($resource){

var _settingsServiceFactory = {

FunctionX = function() { // do something },
ResourceSrvc = function() {
        return  $resource('http://localhost:9000/settings', {}, {
            update: {method:'PUT'}});

};

return _settingsServiceFactory 

});
```

Either you are doing same thing .

Comment: And the call for my REST methods wont change? like "SettingsService.query()"

Comment: call it like SettingsService.ResourceSrvc.query(), SettingsService.FunctionX().

Answer (score 0):

Considering your edit, this is one way you would go about adding more functions

```
var settingsService = angular.module('settingsService',['ngResource']);

 settingsService.service('SettingsService', ['$resource', function($resource){
//use a variable to hold the resource object
var settingsUpdater = $resource('http://localhost:9000/settings', {}, {
    update: {method:'PUT'}
});

   //declare the other functions you want
function doX()
{
  //do something
}

function doY(args)
{
 //do something with args
}

//after declaring all your functions you can return a hash of them

return
{
   //the key will be what you invoke using SettingsService and you can call it what you like. I will call it invokedoX....yes I suck at naming

   invokedoX:function()
   {
      doX();
   },
   invokedoY:function(args)
   {
      doY(args);
   },
   //your resource object

   updateSettings:function(successCallback,errorCallback){
     //settingsUpdater is what I called it above
     settingsUpdater.update(successCallback,errorCallback);
   }
}
```

}]);

For your resource object, the data will be returned in the successCallback in the controller or directive or wherever you are injecting the service. Note the successCallback looks like

```
function(data)
{
}
```

and the error callback looks like

```
function(error)
{
}
```

so in your controller, it will look like

```
SettingsService.updateSettings(function(data){}, function(error){});
```

Hope this gives you a good start.